# What is the limit of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^3}{n^4}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals, summation

> Find the following limit:
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^3}{n^4}$$

Should I approximate this with integrals?

Comment: Hint: this is $\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac kn\right)^3$ . What do you know about Riemann sums?

Comment: "Should I approximate this with integrals?" **Yes**. Next question?

Answer (score 4):

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^3}{n^4}= \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4n^4}=\frac{1}{4}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Use Riemann summation
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^3}{n^4}=\int_0^1 x^3\,dx$$